# Can I edit an armature's size through its bounding box?

Tags: armature, dimensions

Let's say I have a human model and I want to give it a certain height. Currently I only see a way using the scale (either with the mouse or by editing the numbers) but I don't even know its initial size so I can only scale it approximately.
So is there a way to see a model's bounding box dimensions and edit them to resize the skeleton?

Answer (score 2):

An armature object doesn't provide it's bounding box size. However the mesh object of your character does. You can scale your mesh object until the height is to your liking (the dimensions are visible in the properties sidebar). By selecting your armature, then shift selecting your mesh, the mesh object is active and will display it's dimensions as both objects get scaled together.

[image]

If your character is made of several items you will only see the size of the active object, a trick there is to add a cube and size it to the height you want, then use it as a reference and resize your character to fit.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, my character is made of several parts. So in this case it is still basically approximate scaling but with a reference to assist. I tried to use Python to compose a total bounding box but it didn't quite work. Here's my attempt, it would be great if someone could fix it (and post it as an answer) or explain why it can't work: http://pastebin.com/Mg5Mczf5.

Comment: [This is an addon I did a while back](https://github.com/sambler/addonsByMe/blob/master/create_bound_box.py) Post your script as a separate question to get feedback.